# Java simple asynchronous HTTPS client

Tags: java, https, httpclient

I need to develop an application that comunicates with an https server.
This application needs to do some asynchronous data transfert.

I first tried to use an HttpsURLConnection and manage the returned inputStream using a separate thread with an observable object. The observer class than would call the update method that would do some stuff.
The problem with this approach is that i read here: [HTTPUrlConnection error (Can't open OutputStream after reading from an inputStream)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673289/httpurlconnection-error-cant-open-outputstream-after-reading-from-an-inputstrea) that HttpUrlConnection can't handle more than a single write/read. That post didn't help me anyway.

I read about Jetty and the Apache HttpClient, but those libraries are 2.8 and 4 megabytes, that is more than 10 times bigger than the application i have to write.

So: I'm looking for a really simple and possibly lightweight java libraries to handle an asynchronous https connection, or a way to use multiple times a connection like the HttpURLConnection (the second solution would be more appreciated as my program doesn't need to do anything more complex and i don't have to import any other libraries).

btw: i'm using the sun httpServer to make the https server if it is useful to know.
If you need me to post some parts of my code to make you better understand what i'm making just ask.

Thanks

Comment: Why not use the Apache HttpClient?  Unless you're writing a smartphone application, an extra 4 megs is meaningless given the time and money you'll save by not having to look elsewhere or roll your own.

Comment: Actualy it is not for a smartphone, but i cannot exclude that it will need to be ported. But anyway, in your opinion does the apache httpclient do what i need in a relative simple way? I mean i don't need to do something complex as i said, once it gives me https and asynchronous requests it does all i need. So if in your opinion the apache client from this point of view is "better" than jetty, ning or similar libraries than it could be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the library size truly matters, you could consider using `HttpCore`. `HttpCore` is a set of low level HTTP transport components Apache `HttpClient` is based on. It's footprint is approximately 200-250 KB.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, tomorrow i'll try to find out which libraries more fits my needs